# Why is the change in cost wrt bias in neural network equal to error in the neuron?

Tags: neural-networks, deep-learning, backpropagation, math, calculus

While reading [the book on neural networks](http://neuralnetworksanddeeplearning.com/chap2.html) by Michael Nielson, I had a problem understanding equation (BP3), which is

$$
\frac{\partial C}{\partial b_{j}^{l}}=\delta_{j}^{l} \tag{BP3}\label{BP3},
$$
which can be translated to plain English as follows

> The change in cost, $C$, with respect to the bias of a neuron, $b_{j}^{l}$, is equal to the error in that neuron, $\delta_{j}^{l}$.

Why would this be the case?

Answer (score 1):

This is just an application of the chain rule. The same chapter has "Proof of the four fundamental equations" section, which proves BP1-2, while PB3-4 are left as exercise to the reader. I agree that it's a good exercise indeed, that's why I encourage you to **stop here and try to prove it yourself using a chain rule**.

Now, if you decided to read further, here's the sketch of a proof.

Recall equations (25) and (29), both *definitions*:

- $z^l$ is a linear transformation of $a^{l-1}$: $z^l = w^l a^{l-1} + b^l$
- $\delta^l$ is a partial derivative of $C$ with respect to $z^l$: $\delta^l  = \dfrac{\partial C}{\partial z^l}$

The chain rule itself:

- the partial derivative of $C$ with respect to $b^l$:

$$\frac{\partial C}{\partial b^l_j} = \sum_k \frac{\partial C}{\partial z^l_k} \frac{\partial z^l_k}{\partial b^l_j}$$

Almost all elements in this sum will be zero, except for one when $k=j$.
The first term in it is by definition $\delta^l_j$, the second term $\dfrac{\partial z^l_j}{\partial b^l_j}$ is $1$, because $z$ is linear with respect to $b$.

The derivative with respect to weights is taken the same way, and differs only in the last term: $z$ is linear with respect to $w$ as well, but with a coefficient $a^{l-1}$.